# C++ ifstream is not reading the entire line from text file

Tags: c++, file, text

I'm implementing a simple program using text files. Users can register/login accounts that are saved to a txt file.

One of the options is to post a message to a "Post board" that will store the user's name followed by all their posts.

For example:

```
 Leo: Hello
 Tony: Bye
```

I'm able to successfully read the text file and output the message to the console but the username is not displaying, only the message.

For refrence I have a postMessage() function that uses getline() to concatante the username using

```
ofstream << getUsername() + ": " + string::message.
```

I have quite a bit of code so I cannot share all of it, however, here are the pieces in question.

```
public:
        char postMessage(User& currentUser, bool loggedIn) {    //Will post a message to the board. Passes a User object.
            if (loggedIn == false) {
                std::cout << "You must be logged in to post!" << std::endl;
                userLoginRegisterPrompt();
                return 0;
            }

            char messageState; //Code to verify if message was posted.
            std::string message; //Actual message string

            std::cout << "Enter your text: " << std::endl;
            std::cin.ignore(); //Clears string buffer.
            getline(std::cin,message);
            std::ofstream post("C:/Users/19097/Desktop/Programs/Registration/Registration/UserPosts/-Posts.txt", std::ios::app); //File with user posts.
            post << currentUser.getUserName() << ": " << message << std::endl;
            logAction(currentUser.getUserID(), "Made a post");
        }
```

Here is the loadPosts() method to read from the text file and display it to console.

```
static bool loadPosts() {   //Will be for viewing the post history.
            std::ifstream post("C:/Users/19097/Desktop/Programs/Registration/Registration/UserPosts/-Posts.txt");
            std::string line;

            if (!post) {
                std::cout << "No board exists!" << std::endl;
                return false;
            }
            while (post >> line) {
                getline(post, line);
                std::cout << line << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

This is what some of the posts read like in the actual txt file.

[image: Post board txt]

This is what shows on the console when using loadPosts()

[image: Console contents]

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read lines. `while (post >> line)` stops at the first whitespace. You even have `std::getline()` elsewhere in your code. Now I'm seeing your entire while loop, what are you attempting by reading as your Boolean expression and then calling `std::getline()`, which will 'fail' due to the whitespace left in the stream by the `(post >> line)`?

Comment: `while (post >> line) { getline(post, line);` is two reads. The first reads up until it hits whitespace. Based on your file that would be something like `Leo:`, The next reads the rest of the line until it ends, this also overwrites whatever was in the string before so the username is lost and only what was on the line after it is printed.

Comment: Change `while (post >> line) { getline(post, line); ... }` to `while (getline(post, line)) { ... }`

Comment: Ah, I see. First read is stopping at white space. Executing loop body. Continuing the line read with getline(). Executing 2nd read of line. Implementation worked perfectly. I appreciate it guys!

Comment: @sweenish It's still being implemented. I'm trying to figure out the best way to extract information from the function call. I've played around with chars as letter codes to branch into different decision statements. I had it on boolean as a way to register if the post was successful. Any pointers?